# curl https sites not working

Tags: curl, https, timeout, port

Now I am trying curl from https sites. but it does not work.

And it shows "curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.example.com port 443: Timed out".

```
C:\Users\jonhs\Desktop\2>curl -v -L https://www.w3schools.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.w3schools.com/
*   Trying 59.24.3.173...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 59.24.3.173 port 443 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to www.w3schools.com port 443: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.w3schools.com port 443: Timed out

C:\Users\jonhs\Desktop\2>
```

So I used --insecure or -k option, but result is same.

Anyway it is working well from http sites. (for example, curl -v -L http://www.adobe.com/)

I am using Windows 10 and curl-7.54.1-win64-mingw as below.

```
C:\Users\jonhs\Desktop\2>curl -V
curl 7.54.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.54.1 OpenSSL/1.1.0f zlib/1.2.11 WinIDN libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.23.1
Release-Date: 2017-06-14
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy

C:\Users\jonhs\Desktop\2>
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Any chance that you are behind a proxy? If so, you need to tell `curl` that you are, so that it could use it. See `http_proxy` environment variable.

Comment: Yes, I am behind a proxy. And I have already set http_proxy environment. And I have tried with -x ip:port option, and it fails with saying curl: (56) Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

Comment: HTTP code 407 from the proxy means that the proxy requires authentication. Did you include your proxy credentials in the proxy URI? It's actually quite nasty, but for a dare, use something like `http://user:passwd@your.proxy.com:8080` (obviously, fill in your actual values).

Comment: Yes, I know about that. so I have already set http_proxy environment variable as http://username:password@ip:8080.

Comment: And I have found one thing, When I use http_proxy environment, it doesn't work. But I have tried with -x option and -U option to setting curl proxy configuration, then It works well. So it says curl doesn't use http_proxy enviroment? I don't believe it, because in url https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html, it says "libcurl respects the proxy environment variables named http_proxy". so is this only for libcurl? I want to know this. Please explain me @vencik. Thanks!

Comment: From a glance, I'd guess you haven't `export`ed your `http_proxy` env. var. You do that either by `export http_proxy=http://blahblah.proxy:8080`, or, for just a one-liner, you may exec. the `curl` like this: `http_proxy=blahblah.proxy:8080 curl -L your.uri...`. (It's a general way to set env. var(s) just for the command executed.) Exporting env. vars means that they will be set even for child processes, not merely for the shell in which you set them.

Comment: You are right that "Exporting env means that they will be set even for child processes, not merely for the shell in which you set them". But I have already set system environment variable of http_proxy=http://user:pass@ip:8080, and I have not tried export env in command line, I only run curl with -x and -U option, and it works well.  Without -x and -U option, though system environment http_proxy is set, curl is not working correctly. So I want to know system environment http_proxy is not working for curl command.

Comment: Hmm, what I didn't realise is that you're running `curl` on Windows, sorry. I'm not much experienced with how env. variables work in Windows natively (I use Cygwin). But people are suggesting it should work (see e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/526710/how-to-set-http-proxy-address-for-wget-under-windows).

Comment: @vencik, Thanks. I appreciate you.